# No counter 'chapter' defined. } - Incompatibility of beamer with mysharedLibrary tex file

Tags: incompatibility

I am working on a project and the document has grown. So, I have divided the content into multiple files and one is a tex file, including my libraries, newcommands, etc. which is shared between my different reports so far.

How?
I put this sharedlibrary file in a specified folder that I have called SharedRoot,
then I include this file by using these two lines of command in the beginning of every report:

```
\newcommand{\myrootadd}{../../SharedRoot}
\input{\SharedRoot/sharedlibrary}
```

Using this file, there is no problem with my reports, and everything is working fine.

Now, I want to make a presentation with beamer, and even in the beginning steps,I receive some errors:

The content of my beamer file is:

```
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}

\newcounter{chapter}
\newcommand{\myrootadd}{../../SharedRoot}
\input{\myrootadd/LibsAndDefs}


\usepackage{default}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

And I get:

```
Command \theorem already defined. \newtheorem{theorem}
```

as well as lots of similar error messages. So, I thought maybe beamer is defining theorem too which conflicts with my own definition in this shared file.

So, I tried \documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}.

then I got this message:

```
No counter 'chapter' defined. }
```

So, I tried adding

```
\newcounter{chapter}
```

Then I do not receive this error but I have no output and receive "Either the file is corrupt or it is in the process of creation." All in all, there is no output.

So, I guess it has not been the best choice to use those two lines.

And this is the conflicting part for the content of my sharedDefinitionAndLibrary file:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{bbm}


%\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {../../SharedRoot/images/} }

%\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithmicx} % Algorithm
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

%\theoremstyle{corollary}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

%\theoremstyle{lemma}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}


\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
```

It would be a "super help" if someone has a clue how this issue could be resolved and I could make a beamer presentation using this sharedlibrary file in the end!

Comment: well the best advice imho is: don't use this file with beamer. beamer is quite a different class, and so instead of repairing in various places your file better write one dedicated for beamer.

Comment: Thanks! It was a very helpful advice indeed! I divided the sharedlibrary file into two files! One for this theorem definitions, etc, 
and the other for the beamer friendly ones.
And the problem solved. Very helpful Thanks!!